# Degeneracy of wavefunction in 1 dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, boundary-conditions

Suppose we have a one-dimensional bound state, with the degenerate eigenstates given by $\psi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$.

Using the Wronskian, we can show that there is no degeneracy, as the two functions are linearly dependent.

$$\psi\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}-\phi\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=c$$

Since both the wavefunctions vanish at $x\rightarrow \infty$, the value of $c$ is $0$. Hence, the Wronskian is $0$, and the wavefunctions are linearly dependent on each other.

Let us now take the example of a particle on a ring. In this case, we know that the wavefunctions are of the form $e^{im\phi}$ or $e^{-im\phi}$. Plugging these into the wronskian, we can show that these are linearly independent and for $m\ne 0$, every state has a degeneracy of $2$.

However, is there a general way of showing this for any periodic wavefunctions in one dimension? Just like in the previous case, we argued that both wavefunctions vanish at infinity, and so the wronskian must be $0$.

Can we make a similar argument for periodic cases, and show directly that the wronskian is not $0$, without calculating the eigenstates explicitly. How can we show that periodic boundary conditions guarantee that the wronskian is not $0$ ?

Comment: The argument for $c=0$ in the infinite line case uses the assumption of bound state (so wavefunctions vanish at $x=\pm\infty$). No similar argument can be made for a particle on a ring. There one may or may not have degeneracy depending on the symmetry of the potential.